# Which kernel is to be used for Face detection using SVM?

Tags: svm, face-detection, libsvm

I'm working on face detection algorithm which extracts Haar-like features and then classifies the face and non faces using SVM. I'll be implementing whole algorithm including SVM in C language because i have to run the code on Stretch SCP board.

I have lot of doubts regarding which kernel is most suitable for face-detection problem; is it linear, RBF or something else?

I already extracted haar-features and tried to classify using libsvm and liblinear but didn't get appropriate results.
Please suggest which kernel to be used and what parameter to be considered ?

Comment: I would suggest that you do all kernels and see the results yourself. This is because which kernel suits you really depends on the application...Hope this helps...

Comment: @lakesh thanks for the suggestion.
I tried only linear kernel till now and it didn't work. I don't know much about other kernels, so i thought may be someone else has done it for the same problem. 
I'll read about other kernels and implement them...

Comment: i started off similar as you... i tried all the kernels..RBF was good for me whereas Linear was good for my friend. Btw, the features were different for both of us... so it really depnds on your application...